# "not all arguments converted during string formatting" Python Django

Tags: python, django

I am programming in Django 1.5 with Python 2.7 on Windows Vista. I am trying to create user profiles. However, when I visit localhost:8000/admin/home/userprofile, I got the 1146, "Table 'demo.home_userprofile' doesn't exist error. Now I have in `models.py` :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class userProfile(models.Model):

    def url(self, filename):
        ruta = "MultimediaData/Users/$s/%s"%(self.user.username, filename)
        return ruta

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = url)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

And Django page is pointing `not all arguments converted during string formatting` error at me. This is a page that allows user to upload picture and phone number. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I am getting this same error in Django 1.6, in one place but not another, in the same views.py file. I have stared at the % making sure it's not a $ in both places about a dozen times. Going nuts. :) I'll add here if I figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
ruta = "MultimediaData/Users/$s/%s"%(self.user.username, filename)
```

To:

```
ruta = "MultimediaData/Users/%s/%s"%(self.user.username, filename)
#                            ^ Notice the sign change
```

You seem to have used a `$` instead of a `%`, which was the problem.

Comment: No it was just the '$' sign. Little mistakes like that.

Answer (score 4):

To make it compaitble with Python 2 or 3...

```
ruta = "MultimediaData/Users/{0}/{1}".format(self.user.username, filename)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you're going to downvote someone, at least give them the courtesy of *why*. There's absolutely nothing wrong with either my answer or @Volatility's answer.